# Excel macro to open a file that gives a "We found a problem with some content..." message

Tags: excel, vba

I have a source directory of excel workbooks and I'd like to write a macro that compiles the data from these workbooks as separate worksheets in a single target workbook.

If I were to open any of the source workbooks manually for the first time I get the message "We found a problem with some content in '*.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes." Clicking "Yes" opens up the file and all of the data is fine. However when I try to automate the process, this message seems to be causing errors when my macro runs Workbooks.Open.

I have tried disabling events to prevent the message from interfering at all.

```
' Disable events to prevent Workbook_Open from triggering
Application.EnableEvents = False

' Open the workbook
Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)

' Re-enable events
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

This errored on the Workbooks.Open line

I have also tried some error handling. The idea would be, if you run into the message, deal with the message so that the workbook can still open

```
On Error Resume Next
Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
' Handle the error (e.g., display a message or take corrective action)
MsgBox "Error opening workbook: " & Err.Description
' Simulate pressing the "Y" key (for "Yes" response)
Application.SendKeys "Y"
End If
On Error GoTo 0 ' Restore default error handling
```

but this errored on the very next line because SourceWorkbook was never set.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try: `Workbooks.Open "File", CorruptLoad:=xlExtractData`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ricardo A (See comment for his response). I changed the line to

```
Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName, ReadOnly:=True, CorruptLoad:=xlExtractData)
```

And it worked. There was no need for any error handling.